# How to maximize non-analytic function over space of variables

Tags: python, search, optimization

I have a very simple question that I thought there might be a solution online but I couldn't find one yet.

I have a (non-mathematical i.e. non-analytical) function that computes a value F based on a set of variables a,b,c,d that come from a set of files/databases/online crawling and I want to find the set of variables a,b,c,d that maximizes F. Searching the whole space of a,b,c,d is not feasible, and using differentials / derivatives is not possible since F is not analytical. I would really appreciate a pointer to which packages/algorithms I could use please, or just how to get started. Much of what I've seen online about python optimization seems to be about analytical/math functions (f(x) = x^2 + ...) and not more non-analytical problems.

For example:

```
def F(a,b,c,d):
   ... a lot of computations from databases, etc using 
   a,b,c,d that are different float values ...
   returns output # output is a float
```

Now, for all values of a,b,c,d where each has possible values let's say [0, 0.1, 0.2, ... 1.0]. The values are discrete and I don't need extreme precision in my optimization.

Now, I want to find the set of values a,b,c,d that gives me the highest F.

Oh, and I have no maximization constraints on either F, a, b, c, d..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to build an answer thanks to everybody's help and comments here. The DEAP documentation was immensely helpful but I wanted to share my answer anyway along with some comments that would hopefully be helpful to others.

I used the OneMax example from here https://github.com/DEAP/deap/blob/b46dde2b74a3876142fdcc40fdf7b5caaa5ea1f4/examples/ga/onemax.py with a walkthrough from here: https://deap.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/ga_onemax.html. I found these two pages also invaluable, operators: https://deap.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/basic/part2.html#next-step and creating types: https://deap.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/basic/part1.html#creating-types

So my solution is here (apologies for formatting, this is my first time posting long code and adding comments). Basically, all you really have to do is to make the fitness evaluation function (here `eval_Inidividual`) be the function F you are trying to optimize. And you can limit the range (and distribution) of each of the N variables/inputs of F by limiting their possible values at initialization (here `random_initialization`) and mutation (here `mutate_inputs`).

Last note: I made my code multicore using the multiprocessing library (just two lines of code and changing which map function you use does it!!). Read more here: https://deap.readthedocs.org/en/default/tutorials/distribution.html

Code (read my comments for more explanation):

```
import random

from deap import base
from deap import creator
from deap import tools

start_clock = time.clock()


NGEN =  100  # number of generations to run evolution on
pop_size = 10000 # number of individuals in the population. this is the number of points in the N-dimensional space you start within
CXPB  = 0.5 # probability of cross-over (reproduction) to replace individuals in population by their offspring
MUTPB = 0.2 # probability of mutation
mutation_inside = 0.05 # prob mutation within individual
num_cores = 6
N = 8 # the number of variables you are trying to optimize over. you can limit the range (and distribtuion) of each of them by limiting their possible values at initialization and mutation.


def eval_Inidividual(individual):
    # this code runs on your individual and outputs the 'fitness' of the individual

def mutate_inputs(individual, indpb):
    # this is my own written mutation function that takes an individual and changes each element in the tuple with probability indpb 
    # there are many great built in such mutation functions

def random_initialization():
    # this creates each individual with an N-tuple where N is the number of variables you are optimizing over

creator.create("FitnessMax", base.Fitness, weights=(-1.0,)) # negative if trying to minimize mean, positive if trying to maximize sharpe. can be a tuple if you are trying to maximize/minimize over several outputs at the same time e.g. maximize mean, minimize std for fitness function that returns (mean, std) would need you to use (1.0, -1.0)
creator.create("Individual", list, fitness=creator.FitnessMax)

toolbox = base.Toolbox()
# Attribute generator
toolbox.register("attr_floatzzz", random_initialization) # i call it attr_floatzzz to make sure you know you can call it whatever you want.
# Structure initializers
toolbox.register("individual", tools.initRepeat, creator.Individual, 
    toolbox.attr_floatzzz, N) # N is the number of variables in your individual e.g [.5,.5,.5,.5,.1,100] that get 
# fed to your fitness function evalOneMax
toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)

import multiprocessing as mp

pool = mp.Pool(processes=num_cores)
toolbox.register("map", pool.map) # these 2 lines allow you to run the computation multicore. You will need to change the map functions everywhere to toolbox.map to tell the algorithm to use a multicored map

# Operator registering
toolbox.register("evaluate", eval_Inidividual)
toolbox.register("mate", tools.cxTwoPoint)
toolbox.register("mutate", mutate_inputs, indpb = mutation_inside)
toolbox.register("select", tools.selTournament, tournsize=3)


def main():
#     random.seed(64)

    pop = toolbox.population(n=pop_size) # these are the different individuals in this population, 
                                    # each is a random combination of the N variables

    print("Start of evolution")

    # Evaluate the entire population
    fitnesses = list(toolbox.map(toolbox.evaluate, pop))
    for ind, fit in zip(pop, fitnesses):
        ind.fitness.values = fit   #this runs the fitness (min mean on each of the individuals)

#     print("  Evaluated %i individuals" % len(pop))

    # Begin the evolution
    for g in range(NGEN):
        print("-- Generation %i --" % g)
        f.write("-- Generation %i --\n" % g)
#         f.write("-- Generation %i --\n" % g)
#         g = open('GA_generation.txt','w')
#         g.write("-- Generation %i --" % g)
#         g.close()

        # Select the next generation individuals
        offspring = toolbox.select(pop, len(pop)) # this selects the best individuals in the population
        # Clone the selected individuals
        offspring = list(toolbox.map(toolbox.clone, offspring)) #ensures we don’t own a reference to the individuals but an completely independent instance.

        # Apply crossover and mutation on the offspring
        for child1, child2 in zip(offspring[::2], offspring[1::2]): #this takes all the odd-indexed and even-indexed pairs child1, child2 and mates them
            if random.random() < CXPB:
                toolbox.mate(child1, child2)
                del child1.fitness.values
                del child2.fitness.values

        for mutant in offspring:
            if random.random() < MUTPB:
                toolbox.mutate(mutant)
                del mutant.fitness.values

        # Evaluate the individuals with an invalid fitness
        invalid_ind = [ind for ind in offspring if not ind.fitness.valid]
        fitnesses = toolbox.map(toolbox.evaluate, invalid_ind)
        for ind, fit in zip(invalid_ind, fitnesses):
            ind.fitness.values = fit

#         print("  Evaluated %i individuals" % len(invalid_ind))

        # The population is entirely replaced by the offspring
        pop[:] = offspring

        # Gather all the fitnesses in one list and print the stats
        fits = [ind.fitness.values[0] for ind in pop]

#         length = len(pop)
#         mean = sum(fits) / length
#         sum2 = sum(x*x for x in fits)
#         std = abs(sum2 / length - mean**2)**0.5

        print("  Min %s" % min(fits))
#         print("  Max %s" % max(fits))
#         print("  Avg %s" % mean)
#         print("  Std %s" % std)

    print("-- End of (successful) evolution --")

    best_ind = tools.selBest(pop, 1)[0]
    print("Best individual is %s with mean %s" % (best_ind, 
        best_ind.fitness.values[0])

    done = time.clock() - start_clock # the clock doens't work on the multicored version. I have no idea how to make it work :)
    print "time taken: ", done, 'seconds'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

p.s.: the clock doens't work on the multicored version. I have no idea how to make it work :)

Answer (score 2):

For a non-analytic function you could explore the parameter space with a genetic algorithm or similar evolutionary computation. Then look for maxima or "hills" within the resultant space to find the solution that maximizes your function. I would suggest using a library rather than writing it yourself; [DEAP](https://github.com/deap/deap) looks quite promising.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have been looking into DEAP and it looks very promising. I will try to post my solution!

Comment: your comment ended up being a great pointer and I was able to use a GA to solve my problem. See solution below (writing it now)

Comment: Glad to hear it! I used a GA solution years ago to optimize the parameters for a trading system where there was no "right" answer. I just had to evaluate the parameter space to see where most of the hills were grouped.

Answer (score 2):

You've broken down your problem very well. This is, as you seem to know, *space search*.

I don't know about libraries for doing this in any language except Prolog (where it's actually the language itself that is the solution engine), but one of the most generally useful space search algorithms is "A star" search, also known as "heuristic-guided optimization". Your problem looks like it lends itself to a nice neighbor of A-star search called "greedy best-first search".

You basically start with some set of parameters, call `F` on those parameters, and then tweak each parameter a bit to see how `F` changes. You head "uphill", accepting the tweak that makes `F` increase by the greatest amount and potentially setting aside the "other" paths to be searched later. This greedily moves you toward a "hilltop" - a local maximum. Once you reach the local maximum you can try searching again from some random combination of parameters. You can even use something like *simulated annealing* to decrease the amount you tweak the parameters by as time goes on - at first searching very chaotically, and then settling down once you know the vague problem terrain.

The only way to **guarantee** an optimal result is to do a complete search, like BFS, but there are many good ways to make it very probabalistically likely you get an optimal result out. Which one will give you the best results fastest depends on `F`: the hill climbing I presented here is best if the mapping between inputs and outputs is at least *close* to a contiguous topology with few discontinuities.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful and confirms my suspicions. I will look into A-star and will try to post my solution code! You are awesome!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used GA instead because it was more suited to my problem and just posted my solution.